# I am opening 3 files in Python. The two read files are fine "with open" but the write file only works using "open"

Tags: python, with-statement

Update: When I tried to get a minimal program today, I realized there is  an `os.system('cmd /k')` line that is probably causing the issue.  I am not sure why but it must be autoclosing the file when I use the `with open`.  @wjandrea thank you for suggesting that.

I am pretty new to python so I might be missing something basic although I have run tutorials and searched on "with" and "open".  Nothing should be changed in the two code fragments below (the rest of the code is mostly comments where I sketched out what I want to do eventually and variable declaration and initialization) except the lines:

`with open(fileDirectory+sigMatchFile, "w") as sigMatch:` which doesn't give output in the file

`sigMatch = open(fileDirectory+sigMatchFile, "w")` which gives output in the file

and the indenting (I went back and tried making sure the empty lines indenting matched the programmed lines although I wasn't sure that was an issue.  It didn't help.)

The "with open" works for the read files but I can't get it to work for the write file.

---

### Code using with open for sigMatch: Yields empty file.

```
with open(fileDirectory+sigMatchFile, "w") as sigMatch:
    sigMatch.write("1 - Testing if opened\n")

    with open(fileDirectory+currentFastaFile, "r") as fasta:
        fl = fasta.readline().split("|")
        currentGene = fl[1]
        fasta.close()
    sigMatch.write("2 - Testing if still open\n")

    with open(fileDirectory+blastpFile, "r")as blastp:
        blpl = blastp.readlines()
        for x in blpl:
            if "significant alignments:" in x:
                print ("significant alignments: " + x)
                sigMatch.write("3 - Testing if still open\n")
                sigMatch.write("significant alignments: " + x +"\n")

        blastp.close()
    sigMatch.close()
```

---

### Code using open for sigMatch: Yields file with written output.

```
sigMatch = open(fileDirectory+sigMatchFile, "w")
sigMatch.write("1 - Testing if opened\n")

with open(fileDirectory+currentFastaFile, "r") as fasta:
    fl = fasta.readline().split("|")
    currentGene = fl[1]
    fasta.close()
sigMatch.write("2 - Testing if still open\n")

with open(fileDirectory+blastpFile, "r")as blastp:
    blpl = blastp.readlines()
    for x in blpl:
        if "significant alignments:" in x:
            print ("significant alignments: " + x)
            sigMatch.write("3 - Testing if still open\n")
            sigMatch.write("significant alignments: " + x +"\n")

    blastp.close()
sigMatch.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'll just note, `close` isn't required in the first chunk of code. The reason to use `with` with file objects is that `with` automatically closes the file for you when you exit the `with` block.

Comment: Thank you - I did realize that the `with` will close the file - I just was trying to make the code segments as alike as possible to see if I could figure out why it didn't work.  I am seriously considering just going with `open` for the write file but I am afraid that it will bite me later because there is something environmental I don't understand.

Comment: Just as a side note: I would suggest using `os.path.join()` instead of concatenating strings by yourself for getting the file's path.

Comment: I had a guess that [`.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) doesn't flush, but it does in fact, which makes sense. I'm not sure what the problem is. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Just in case, if fileDirectory stands for the folder the python file is in, you can use '.\'+sigMatchFile.

Comment: The first implementation (the one with 'with') seems to work fine on my Mac. Other than the redundant 'close', I don't think there's an issue with the code itself.

Comment: When I tried to get a minimal program today, I realized there is  an os.system('cmd /k') line that is probably causing the issue.  I am not sure why but it must be autoclosing the file when I use the with open.  @wjandrea thank you for suggesting that.